# python-opencv face recogniton and verification without face training

Tags: python, opencv

i am new to `python` `opencv` and i want to build a software that verifies if the uploaded image belongs to the same user or not but i in `opencv` you need to train the faces in order to get precised results, the problem is that the faces are likely `random` with only 1 photo as described above.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please follow the stackoverflow guidelines to ask a question and describe/show what you have tried or researched (for example, you should have googled face recognition with python which would give you tons of resources).

Answer (score 0):

i am using google facenet for the implementation of face recognition system.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use deepface? This could be handled in just a line of code.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
result  = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg")
```

The library also wraps several state-of-the-art techniques such as VGG-Face, Google FaceNet, OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID and Dlib.

```
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[1])
```